# Is it possible to extract the download syllabus link with requests or scrapy without selenium

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to extract the download syllabus link from this website-
https://www.simplilearn.com/big-data-and-analytics/python-for-data-science-training

The link is not available on page source, and I was not able to see anything in network tab.
But if we click the link, the link opens in a different tab.

I know, it is possible to extract using selenium, but can we extract without selenium?

[image]

the link is hidden with '#' in page source.

So I am not sure, how to extract the links.
I know that I won't be able to extract using xpath or css.
Can someone help me?

Comment: When you click on `download syllabus` link it opens up a modal `ebook-modal modal course-popup  ` which needs ur phone number, once you fill that then only it will display the pdf to you

Comment: You can very well achieve this using `selenium`, let me know if you need the code

Comment: Thanks @HimanshuPoddar for answering, I wanted to know is it possible to extract pdf url without using selenium?

Comment: nope, its generated dynamically, you ll have to use some module that imitates a browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case,

The URL link is base64 encoded in the div with id = "DownloadSyllabus2", on its `data-url`  attribute (right above the a href you are mentioning):

`aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2ltcGxpbGVhcm4uY29tL2ljZTkvcGRmcy9hZ2VuZGEvb25saW5lL0RhdGElMjBTY2llbmNlJTIwd2l0aCUyMFB5dGhvbi5wZGY=`

**You need to decode it using base64 and you will get the desired url:
https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/pdfs/agenda/online/Data%20Science%20with%20Python.pdf**

This is not a magic solution for all cases like this, but it works for this website and is the best solution here.

So, Data extraction is not always about the solutions, but to be able to reverse engineer the website logic.

Happy Scraping :)

Comment: Hello, can you explain how did you find out about the base64 encoded tag?

Comment: Thank You so much Neha Setia Nagpal, for this idea..

Comment: @Hanna Honestly, that element sounded a bit fishy so i tried decoding. And it was the link OP  was looking for. As I mentioned, analyse the website and trying reverse engineering can surprise you sometimes while extracting Data...